# how to read the logs from the previous File Extension DATE stored log files into elasticsearch through logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

The previous days logs are stored as File Extension DATE format.
[Please refer the pic of the place where logs are stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOvhH.png)

Please find the code below which I have written in config file.

```
input { 
file {
path => "D:/elasticsearch-2.3.3/logs/elasticsearch.log.2016-08-24"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}

filter {
date {
match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}
}
output 
{
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't add your code as screenshot, but please paste it and format it as text. Please also describe your problem more clearly. Your question is not very well asked. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have edited the question and written the code and uploaded a pic of the place where logs are stored. Please refer it.